# Google Drive Save Button + Amazon Cloudfront URL = XHR Error

Tags: google-drive-api, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a Google Save Button on a website, but when I'm trying to link a Cloudfront url (which is displayed as CNAME as a subdomain of our domain), I keep getting a XHR error, how to solve?

Cheers,

Sjoerd

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: The HTML gives 'Failed Download XHR error', and console 'Blocked loading mixed active content'. So it is due a crossdomain error, but I can't get it solved with cloudfront...